# jquery show array of objects in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects:

```js
[{message:'test string', fileName:'test name'},{message:'test string2', fileName:'test name2'},{message:'test string3', fileName:'test name3'}]
```

and I want this appended on the dom on `$('.errors')`
shown as (with linebreaks)

```
test name : test string 

test name2 : test string2 

test name3 : test string3
```

I hope someone can help me with this or send me good links with how to achieve this

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate the array and then just *apply* `append` method.

```js
var errors = [{message:'test string', fileName:'test name'},{message:'test string2', fileName:'test name2'},{message:'test string3', fileName:'test name3'}]

errors.forEach(error => {
  $('#errors').append(`${error.message} - ${error.fileName}<hr>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="errors"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is your answer. hope it helps.

```
var array = [{message:'test string', fileName:'test name'},{message:'test string2', fileName:'test name2'},{message:'test string3', fileName:'test name3'}]

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    var obj = array[i];
    var message = obj.message;
    var fileName= obj.fileName;
    $('#errors').append('' +message : fileName+ '<br>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly accumulate your array of objects into an HTML string using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and then once you have done that query and append your HTML string to the DOM. By firstly creating the HTML string you're making it so you only need to append and query the DOM once.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [{message:'test string', fileName:'test name'},{message:'test string2', fileName:'test name2'},{message:'test string3', fileName:'test name3'}];
const html = arr.reduce((str, {message, fileName}) => `${str}<span>${fileName} : ${message}</span><br /><br />`, ``);

$('.error').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="error">
</div>
```

A regular for loop will also work to generate the string if you're more comfortable using that:

```js
const arr = [{message:'test string', fileName:'test name'},{message:'test string2', fileName:'test name2'},{message:'test string3', fileName:'test name3'}];
let html = ``;
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const obj = arr[i];
  html += `<span>${obj.fileName} : ${obj.message}</span><br /><br />`;
}

$('.error').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="error">
</div>
```